# Алгоритм сортировки динамичного массива

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, разработка-игр, actionscript

Делаю игру. Есть динамичный массив отображаемых объектов. (Объекты добавляются и удаляются из него в течении процесса игры) Задача состоит в том, что бы сделать что-то наподобие принципа изометрии. Те графические объекты у которых "**y**" меньше будут находиться под теми, у которых "**y**" больше. Буду менять *ChildIndex*.

Подскажите пожалуйста алгоритм. Да еще что бы по производительней)

Comment: а пробовали добавлять элементы в список уже сортированным. то есть если есть `1,3,5` добавляете элемент `4` после `3`. Не нужно будет сортировать список

Comment: то есть при добавлении в массив элемента, сразу его сопоставлять с имеющимися, и размешать уже в нужном месте? спасибо, попробую

Comment: да точно. Используйте бинарный поиск. Думаю для вас он самый подходяший.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это называется "**Z-последовательность**"

## решение:

```
addChild(clip);
plant_arr.push(clip);
 
clip_arr.sortOn("y", Array.NUMERIC); 
 
for (var i:int = 0; i < clip_arr.length; i++) 
{
    addChild(clip_arr[i]);
}
```

Если же у нас имеется вместо Array - Vector, в котором есть только .sort() можем написать свою сортировку:

```
        vector.sort(sorter);  

        function sorter(a:T, b:T):Number 
        {
            if(a > b) {
                return 1;
            }
            else if(a < b) {
                return -1;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае вам необходим не столько подходящий алгоритм сортировки, сколько подходящая структура данных. Она называется *сбалансированное бинарное дерево*.

Данные в таком дереве хранятся в отсортированном виде, поэтому бинарный поиск обеспечивает время O(log N). В отличие от массива, вставка и удаление данных в бинарное дерево требуют времени O(log N) вместо O(N). Балансировка спасает от вырожденных случаев, когда дерево превращается, фактически, в список.

Существуют разные способы поддержки дерева в сбалансированном состоянии, в частности *Красно-Чёрные деревья* и *АВЛ-деревья*.

Как правило, сбалансированное бинарное дерево уже реализовано в стандартной библиотеке, поэтому поищите подходящую структуру данных. Это может быть какой-нибудь `SortedDictionary` или `std::map`.

**UPDATE**

Попроще ситуация выглядит так: если вам нужны отсортированные данные, вы можете хранить их в массиве и сортировать всякий раз, когда они вам потребуются. Временная сложность общих алгоритмов сортировки составляет O(N×log N). Такая запись означает, что (упрощённо) при увеличении размера массива в *k* раз, время работы алгоритма возрастёт пропорционально (k×N)×log(k×N). Это не очень хорошая скорость, поскольку если размер массива вырастает в 10 раз, время его сортировки возрастает, скажем, в 30 раз.

Если этот массив нужен вам постоянно, например, для быстрого бинарного поиска, имеет смысл отсортировать его в самом начале и затем использовать. Бинарный поиск позволяет находить элементы за время O(log N), и это очень быстро. В массиве из 1000 элементов вы найдёте нужный всего за 10 сравнений, и это в худшем случае.

Ситуация усложняется, если нужно во время работы добавлять и удалять элементы в массив. Скажем, нужно вставить новый элемент, которого нет в массиве. Сначала надо его найти, а если не нашли, вставить в нужное место, чтобы массив остался отсортированным. Операция поиска занимает O(log N) времени, как мы уже говорили, а вот вставка элемента в середину массива занимает O(N) времени. Это снова долго: для вставки элемента в массив из 1000 элементов потребуется каждый раз двигать в среднем половину массива, то есть порядка 500 элементов.

Для удаления нам опять придётся сдвигать в среднем половину массива. Если операции вставки и удаления происходят регулярно, их надо делать быстрыми. Один из вариантов: использовать структуру данных, вставка и удаление в которую выполняются очень быстро. Одна из подходящих структур — упорядоченное бинарное дерево (*бинарное дерево поиска*).

В каждом узле такого дерева хранится значение элемента и две ссылки: на левое поддерево, и на правое поддерево. Элемент в корне левого поддерева меньше текущего элемента, а элемент в корне правого — больше.

Поиск, вставка и удаление в таком дереве выполняются за время O(log N). То, что нам нужно. Одна беда: если с такое дерево вставлять уже отсортированные элементы, они все будут попадать в левое (или правое) поддеревья. Получится вырожденное двоичное дерево, где все левые поддеревья пусты, а дерево уходит вправо.

[image: обычное упорядоченное дерево и вырожденный случай]

Поиск, вставка и удаление в вырожденном дереве опять будут выполняться за медленное время O(N). Чтобы решить и эту проблему, дерево балансируют, то есть время от времени перестраивают его так, чтобы в левых и правых поддеревьях было приблизительно поровну элементов (упрощённо).

Балансировка требует времени, но зато она всегда позволяет находить, вставлять и удалять элемент за время, пропорциональное O(log N).

Есть разные способы балансировки, о которых я уже написал выше. Проще всего погуглить их, они прекрасно описаны и в википедии на русском языке, и на других ресурсах. Кроме того, полезно прочитать одну из самых классических книг по этой теме: Никлаус Вирт, Алгоритмы и структуры данных. Для удобства гугления я в этом ответе выделял термины, которые можно гуглить *наклонным шрифтом*.

Comment: Уточните, такое дерево оптимально для нечастой вставки в середину, регулярной пересортировки и чтения? Судя по ТЗ автору нужны именно такие свойства структуры.

Comment: Я ничего не понимаю из написанных выше слов. Правда. А можно пожалуйста как то по проще выразится?

Comment: @АндрейНевский Обновил ответ. Вряд ли получится намного проще, всё равно придётся читать много материала. Однако, это база, пригодится при разработке практически любой программы, поэтому не жалейте потраченного времени.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko Большое спасибо за столь развернутый ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Вначале надо определиться с требованиями к алгоритму.

Как часто перестраивается список, как часто идет добавление элементов, как часто удаление, чтение.

В своей игре у нас много движущихся объектов, а времени на поиск оптимального алгоритма с кэшированием нет, поэтому мы перестраиваем этот список каждый кадр - производительность вполне приемлимая. Таким образом, мы:

1. проходим по всем элементам и проверяем попадают ли они на экран (алгоритмы отсечения заведомо-невидимых объектов это отдельная тема)
2. сохраняем в простой массив координаты и указатели на эти потенциально видимые объекты
3. сортируем алгоритмом QuickSort (по оси `Y` и `X`)
4. рисуем все объекты по порядку отсортированного массива